# Content inside of a div without braking the aspect ratio of a div

Tags: html, css

Can anyone please explain me why am I getting scrolling bar when I put content inside the div below.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
div {
  top:0;
    position: relative;
    background: url("https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-k8IX2Mkf0Jo/U4ze2gNn7CI/AAAAAAAA7xg/iKxa6bYITDs/s0/HOT+Balloon+Trip_Ultra+HD.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

If I remove the `br` tags inside of the div - scroll bar removed as well.

Overflow: hidden - is not an option.

I want to be able use content inside of a div, but so the div will remain the aspect ratio - how can I achieve this, please?

Comment: Why would you put all of these `<br>` into your `<div>` anyway?

Comment: @domsson Just an example of a content I want to use

Comment: your explanation is complete. Can you carify your need?

Comment: do you need it to stop resizing before it starts to overflow or what?

Comment: @krishnar My need is to remain the aspect ratio of the div with background image, put some content inside of this div **and** all that without having an extra space after this div, so the next divs will fit exactly where they should

Comment: @lessismore   set min-width, min-height, max-width, max-height. This will maintain aspect ratio

Comment: @krishnar can you show me how this will maintain the aspect ratio of the entire div? Here an example: https://jsfiddle.net/06pwarta/

Comment: @lessismore check my solution .Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this solution. Inside outer div place inner div with absolute position, because you don't want to lose proportion anyway. Inside inner div place content you want.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/612rhf36/)

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just came across with this, the same one solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css

Answer (score 0):

Specify the width and height to keep the aspect ratio and add overflow-y:hidden; to remove the scroll bar.

```
<div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
div {
  top:0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    background: url("https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-k8IX2Mkf0Jo/U4ze2gNn7CI/AAAAAAAA7xg/iKxa6bYITDs/s0/HOT+Balloon+Trip_Ultra+HD.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Why would I need to force it for 300x40? I need it to be responsive

Answer (score 0):

**In this code I set min, max width and height so that width/height wont change whether content is too much  or less.This will maintain aspect ratio**

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
div.bg {
  color: #f00;
  top:0;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: url("https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-k8IX2Mkf0Jo/U4ze2gNn7CI/AAAAAAAA7xg/iKxa6bYITDs/s0/HOT+Balloon+Trip_Ultra+HD.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /*
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>CONTENT
</div>
<div>ANOTHER CONTENT</div>
```

Comment: I wish it could be true, as I don't like messing up with absolute positioning, but this doesn't keep the aspect ratio. And what is the story with min-max width-hight if it's the same value anyway?

Comment: @lessismore no its not.   you can set to whatever you want

Comment: Can you show an example where it will meet the needs?

Comment: @lessismore  see my code. I update min,max values. check aspect ratio. it wont change whether you add or remove br

Comment: @lessismore is that what you are looking for?